# How can detect an auto DDoS attack?

Tags: ddos

I would like to know if there is a way to detect auto DDoS on a website?

Currently, we have a site in .NET that static resources (styles and JS) are being down totally on random date-time, so we have tried everything like permissions, etc. However, nothing seems to work.

Any help or hint on what can be causing the issue to stop loading static resources randomly? We think this could have something related to a DDoS attack, but we would like to know how to detect it and probably skip this option if that is not happening.

Btw, this issue is fixed when we recycle the IIS app pool in the server.

Comment: Here's a hint - put your static files on something other than your application server. Try nginx or Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if a DDoS attack actually occured by checking the web server logs.

Is there any unusual number of connections, are the request slower than usual ?

If it is just some part of the website who refuses to load, caching may be an issue.

There are several Web Application Firewalls that can help detecting DDoS attacks, but I have no experience regarding their efficiency.

Regards